# Linux reading into an array

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to read in two fields from the **/etc/passwd** file (1,6) into an array. 
I can get the fields into a variable but not into an array.

This code will get all users over 1000 and return the user and home directory.

```
users=$(awk -F'[:]' '{if ($3 >= 1000 && $3 != 65534) print $1}' /etc/passwd)
```

Comment: This code only returns the user, not the home directory. Further, what would your array look like if you were to define it manually for, say, 2 users?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while IFS=: read -r user _ uid _ _ homedir _
do
    (( uid > 999 && uid != 65534 )) && arr+=( "$user":"$homedir" )
done < "/etc/passwd"

printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

This script process `/etc/password` reading each line in a while loop.

- Each line is split on the value of `$IFS`.
- The `$IFS` is set to `:` only for the duration of the read command.
- The values split are assigned to several variables (user, uid, homedir, _).
- The variable `_` is used to discard values that are not needed.
- Then, only if the `uid` is valid, a record is added to the array (the `+=(…)`).
- The records in the array are joined with a colon (`:`)

Answer (score 0):

To offer an `awk` alternative to [soronta's helpful and well-explained answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40180546/45375):

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra usersAndHomeDirs < \
  <(awk -F':' '$3 >= 10 && $3 != 65534 { print $1, $6 }' /etc/passwd)
```

- `-d ''` tells `read` to read the entire input *as a whole*,
- `IFS=$'\n'` tells `read` to split the input into *lines*, and store them in elements of array (`-a`) `usersAndHomeDir` (`-r` turns off `\` interpretation in the input, and in most cases should be added by default).
- `< <(awk ..)` then uses a process substitution (`<(...)`) to make `awk` output `"<user> <home-dir>"` lines, and feeds them to `read` via stdin (`<`).

Note that each element of `"${usersAndHomeDirs[@]}"` is now a *single* `"<user> <home-dir>"` string, which you'll have to split into its components later.
(Bash doesn't offer a way to fill two arrays in parallel.)

To use something other than a space as the separator, pass `-v OFS=<separator-string>` to the `awk` command.

Letting `awk` process the input file will be much faster in general than doing it in a shell loop, though in this particular case it may not make much of a difference, if your `/etc/passwd` file is smallish.